# Terraform Public Registry - Host key verification failed

Tags: git, terraform

I'm trying to use a module from a public [repo](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/ahmad-hamade/config/eks/latest/submodules/eks-iam-role-with-oidc), but doing

```
module "eka_iam_role_ca" {
  source = "git@github.com:ahmad-hamade/terraform-eks-config.git//eks-iam-role?ref=TAG"

  cluster_name     = local.cluster_name
  role_name        = "cluster-autoscaler"
  service_accounts = ["kube-system/cluster-autoscaler"]
  policies         = [data.aws_iam_policy_document.cluster_autoscaler.json]

  tags = {
    Terraform = "true"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}
```

Throws:

```
│ Error: Failed to download module
│ 
│ Could not download module "eka_iam_role_ca" (role.tf:1) source code from "git::ssh://git@github.com/ahmad-hamade/terraform-eks-config.git?ref=TAG": error
│ downloading 'ssh://git@github.com/ahmad-hamade/terraform-eks-config.git?ref=TAG': /usr/bin/git exited with 128: Cloning into
│ '.terraform/modules/eka_iam_role_ca'...
│ load pubkey "/home/root1/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format
│ git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
│ fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
│ 
│ Please make sure you have the correct access rights
│ and the repository exists.
```

I had no problems using git so far, I can still use my own repos without a problem, but I'm not sure why this one refuses to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I had no problems using git so far, I can still use my own repos without a problem

Yes, but that was with your account.

The module is using `/home/root1/.ssh/id_rsa`, meaning it is not executed with your account, and do not have access to the same keys (or any key at all).

You need to make sure the process is executed with the right account (one with the expected keys).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - why would the dev assume I have access to his account? How would I use this module without his keys?

Comment: @TFaws that's not "the dev's" account. That's the account named `root1` on whatever computer you are running `terraform`. Are you running terraform with `sudo`, or running it on some sort of CI/CD platform?

Comment: sudo, its on my own machine. What keys do I need?

Comment: @TFaws THe point is: if it was working using your own account, your `root1` account (since you are using `sudo`) would need to have the same keys as your `~/.ssh` for the script to succeed.